# Why am I getting messages from cloudfront in my error log?

Tags: javascript, error, amazon-cloudfront

I frequently have messages like this in my websites error log:

```
"Script error.". URL: https://e3m4drct5m1ays.cloudfront.net/items/loaders
/loader_21.js?pid=21&systemid=13504281c5a501837196c23300f84e66&aoi=1327214632&
zoneid=16620&cid=HK&rid=Hong%20Kong%20(general)&ccid=Kowloon&dma=0. 
Line number: 0 Error name: Stack:
```

Now I don't actually know what cloudfront is or what it does. And I do not refer to this script in my site.  So why would I be getting js error logged as if it was a script being run on my own site?  This is using elmah logging.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Cloudfront is Amazon's Content Delivery Network. This answer should help explain the messages in the log: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9197918/why-is-cloudfront-loading-scripts-in-my-web-app-i-dont-use-it.

The conclusion is

> As mentioned upfront already, I share the initial conclusion that the
>   code itself is probably harmless, although the underlying technology
>   can most certainly be (ab)used for malicious intents as well due to
>   its very nature of mocking with client side JavaScript...